# Compute the 10th derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

$f(x) = (\cos(5x^2) - 1 )/ x^2 $ at $x = 0$

We were given the hint to use the MacLaurin series for f(x).

I get how to do it if it was just $\cos(5x^2)$ but what would I do with the other values in f(x)?

The answer is supposed to be -78750000

Comment: There is a much easier way.  Write down the MacLaurin series for $\cos(5x)$.  Then subtract $1$.  Then divide each term in that series by $x^2$.

Comment: Write $\cos(5x^2)$ out through the $x^{12}$ term, since you said you get how to do that.  Then subtract $1$, and then divide by $x^2$.  What's left?

Comment: The coefficient $c_{10}$ of $x^{10}$ is the $10$th derivative at $0$, divided by $10!$. So the $10$-th derivative at $0$ is $10!c_{10}$. Find $c_{10}$ by finding the Maclaurin expansion of $\frac{\cos(5x^2)-1}{x^2}$ the easy way.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: I think you meant $\cos(5x^2)$.

Comment: @Amzoti Yes, you are correct.  So take the MacLaurin series for $\cos(x)$ and substitute $x$ with $5x^2$.